# Azure - Migration from on-premises to Azure

Tags: azure, paas

We are planning to migrate our Enterprise Application(s) from on-premises to Azure. Below are the high level details about our current infrastructure.

1. One Web Server hosting multiple WebSites (around 30 websites)
2. One Server with SSIS installed in it which processes huge data coming from multiple data sources and dumps the data into Pre-production database server explained in #3 below
3. Two Servers (Pre-production and Production) with SQL Server hosted in them where some jobs run on Pre-Produciton Server and the data gets replicated to the Production database server.
4. One Server where SSRS is hosted that uses data (and stored procedures) from Pre-Production database Server.

Could you please let us know if it is a good option to migrate the current infrastructe to PAAS? Is it really possible? We are also planning to leverage the other Azure features like Load Balancing on Web Servers and High availability on Production Database server with Active-Passive servers.

Comment: This is wide-open: broad and opinion-soliciting. There's no way to answer it.  And it's unclear what you mean by PaaS: Services to replace what's running in your VM's? If that's the case, you need to see if there are services which provide the same functionality. Finally: it's not a programming question and doesn't belong on StackOverflow.

Comment: I agree with David, if you have more general questions, please ask them here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=ssdsgetstarted&filter=alltypes&sort=lastpostdesc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For migration scenarios, please see the following: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-cloud-migrate/